# diagnosing spurious hard-drive spin-down

Tags: macos, hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, osx-mountain-lion

I've got an external USB drive that is being used for backup purposes.  Occasionally it will spuriously spin-down and Mac OS X will complain that the disk wasn't ejected properly.  One reason I have seen suggested is that this is a known bug in OS X and that disabling "Put hard disks to sleep when possible" is a workaround.  However, after trying this, the disk has subsequently exhibited the same behavior.

It also sometimes occurs that unplugging and re-plugging the USB cable will result in the drive starting to spin up but then immediately spinning back down anywhere from 1/4 second - 2.5 seconds after the USB is plugged back into, while other times the drive continues to run for hours of days.

When the disk is running it has been checked for errors, and everything is in order. There are no strange noises coming from the drive, and other than the spurious spin-downs it works perfectly.  When it does spin down it has been observed to automatically spin itself back up properly some time (minutes or hours) later.

Comment: Does this hdd have a power supply?

Comment: @Ramhound it has an external "wall wart" 12V supply.  Unloaded it reads 12.25V.  I haven't measured it under load as there isn't an easy way to do that.

Comment: If you have another power supply that will work you might try that.  I had a SD external one go out on me, caused the drive to continuously attempt to power up, complete failure in my case but similar.  the actual drive works perfectly fine.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks i'll try that... usually it takes days or weeks to reproduce but today it has been rather easy to do so, so hopefully if it fixes it will be easy to tell.